# What is the correct Push Up technique for Serratus Anterior Engagement?

Tags: push-ups, form

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALzFr2GT-Is) trainer [Nick Tumminello](http://nicktumminello.com/) recommends:

> Hands closer together, slightly elevated and slightly internally
>   rotated.

But in the comments, a "Sylvester Koh" (no idea who he is, but his comments sound informed and so I wanted to confirm or deny) agrees with a "Kirstine Vest Have" who says:

> Funny. A study using EMG says the hands should be externally rotated
>   for max activation of the serratus ant.. Not internally rotated.

(Perhaps [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25364120), though it's for an unstable surface.)

Sylvester Koh also says:

> If you [have] clinical reason in terms of muscle biomechanics and physiology,
>   internal rotation will result in the recruitment of the pectoral
>   muscles ( internal rotators) which defeat the purpose of this
>   exercise. Push up plus serves to isolate serratus anterior muscle
>   activation only and removes as much recruitment of pectorals as
>   possible. Besides performing external rotation, at the shoulders,
>   isometric shoulder horizontal abduction would further deactivate the
>   pectoral muscle via reciprocal inhibition.
>
> In summary, in order to perform the perfect push up plus exercise,
>   there should be thoracic kyphosis, lower cervical flexion, lumbar
>   flexion with posterior pelvic tilt, shoulder external rotation, and
>   isometric shoulder horizontal abduction, in order to fully activate
>   the serratus anterior muscles.

And

> Place your palms on the floor in a standard push up position such that
>   your palms are directly under your shoulders. Try to contract your
>   posterior deltoids such that your wanna bring your hands away from one
>   another. Next flex your neck gently and focus on protracting your
>   scapular as much as position. I would recommend that your keep your
>   scapular protracted for as long as you can rather that continuously
>   move through the range of motion like in this video. Make sure that
>   your abdominal muscles and buttock muscles are contracted fully
>   throughout the exercise such that your lower back is flat out.

So my questions are who is right, and what is the best form? Thanks!

Comment: This question is too dependant on a persons specific condition and not suited to a "general" statement. A physiotherapist should advice an athlete on their movements if they have a winged scapula.

Comment: If your PT said to google it, time to get a new PT.

Comment: Echoing @rrirower you pay a PT/Physio to answer these questions. Get a new/better PT/physio

Comment: Actually, I don't. This was a public health service PT. Anyway, I don't really think that's moot. Plenty of other questions tagged [tag:form] have detailed answers, so I live in hope ...

Comment: As it stands, this question is now suitable. Careful on your wording in the question though: "best" is a subjective term, there are different types of push-up and they all do different things, some better than others.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting study on this subject:

**EMG activity of the serratus anterior and trapezius muscles during the different phases of the push-up plus exercise on different support surfaces and different hand positions**
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4968519/

In the conclusion you'll find:

> SA showed significant increase in activity in hand position P3,

P3 being a hand position with the fingers rotated internally, compared to P1/P2 where the fingers were parallel.

Comment: Thanks for finding this. I had look myself and found one paper supporting external rotation - though on an unstable surface (I put edited my question and added the link). Also, [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27632840) suggests humeral elevation of 120 degrees. Ah, science. A study confirming every opinion!